# How to invalidate useQuery cache from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a parent component which needs to invalidate the query cache of a child component:

```js
const Child = () => {
    const { data } = useQuery('queryKey', () => fetch('something'))
    return <Text>{data}</Text>
}

const Parent = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Clean up happened')
        return () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['queryKey'])
    })

    return <Child />
}
```

I can see that `Clean up happpened` is logged out, but the query cache for `queryKey` is not invalidated.

Is there something wrong with how I am using `#invalidateQueries`? Or that query cache of a component (Child) cannot be invalidated by another component (Parent)

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-invalidation), you should use:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Clean up happened')
        return () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['queryKey'] })
        };
    })

    return <Child />
}
```

That is, of course, if you are using the latest version.